# php array into multidimentional array foreach

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array: $types of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat] => Main
            [type] => name0        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat] => Main
            [type] => Name1        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat] => Main
            [type] => Name2        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [cat] => Main
            [type] => Name3        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [cat] => Secondary
            [type] => Name4        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [cat] => Secondary
            [type] => Name5        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [cat] => Secondary
            [type] => Name6        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [cat] => Other
            [type] => Name7
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [cat] => Other
            [type] => Name8
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [cat] => Other
            [type] => Name9
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [cat] => Other
            [type] => name10
        )

)
```

And I'd like to re-build it as a multi directional array. But grouped together by cat
so they'd be Main, Secondary, and Other *those do or could change from the database. As more get added over time, so using `$types['cat']` would be recommended.

Also I have another one. that has cat1/cat2 I'll need to do the same thing with but after i get this one working, i'm hoping i can work that one out.

I've looked on here, and on google. and here has a few similar examples, but I wasn't able to get any of them to work right. As far as I can tell, I think the best route would be to use `foreach()` and then build a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?
$all = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'cat'=>'Main','type'=>'Name0'),
    array('id'=>2, 'cat'=>'Main','type'=>'Name1'),
    array('id'=>3, 'cat'=>'Main','type'=>'Name3'),
    array('id'=>4, 'cat'=>'Sec','type'=>'Name4'),
    array('id'=>5, 'cat'=>'Sec','type'=>'Name5'),
    array('id'=>6, 'cat'=>'Sec','type'=>'Name6'),
);

$result = array();
foreach($all as $array){
    $result[$array['cat']][] = array('id'=>$array['id'],'type'=>$array['type']);
}

die(print_r($result));
```

Comment: woq. thats perfect. you don't know all the things i've looked up and tried, and modified, and was going crazy cause i could'nt get it to work. like this one for example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085927/php-foreach-loop-to-build-multi-array?rq=1)  ... But thank you. that seems so simple.

Comment: Ok. so it didn't work as well as i thought it would. d'oh. that seemed to work. but failed on the $json_encode() not encoding it correctly. but it's a great start.